# AS3 For statement access movieclip within movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have added:

sub1_btn

Within sub1_btn there is a movieclip called "arrow".

Using this code I am able to access it and tween it:

```
TweenMax.to(sub2_btn.arrow, 1, {rotation: -0});
```

However, using this code within a FOR statement (as there are 2), I am not

```
for (var i:int = 1; i<3; i++){
                TweenMax.to(["sub"+i+"_btn"].arrow, 1, {rotation: -0});
            }
```

What is wrong with the above code? The error is:

Error: Cannot tween a null object.
    at com.greensock::TweenLite()
    at com.greensock::TweenMax()
    at com.greensock::TweenMax$/to()
    at src::main/pullSub()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
for (var i:int = 1; i<3; i++){
    TweenMax.to(this["sub"+i+"_btn"].arrow, 1, {rotation: -0});
}
```

The problem is that `["sub"+i+"_btn"]` creates a new array, and that array doesn't contain an object `arrow`. But when you use `this["sub"+i+"_btn"]` you access the movie clip `sub[i]_btn` as you want.